# DSL Query: Sale Amount Per Second in a Five Minute Window

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I am trying to get the total amount of sale divide by 300 secs to get the sale amount per second in a five minute window

I am so far only able to construct the query until here. There seems to be no way to do a division on “total_value_five_mins”.

My elasticsearch version is 2.3

Tried all the elasticsearch docs can’t understand a single one.

```
{ 
  "size": 0,
  "query": {   
    "aggs" : {
        "five_minute_data" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "timestamp",
                "interval" : "5m"
            },
            "aggs": {
              "total_value_five_mins": {
                "sum": {
                  "field": "sales"
                }
              }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use scripting in your `sum` aggregation like this:

```
{ 
  "size": 0,
  "query": {   
    "aggs" : {
        "five_minute_data" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "timestamp",
                "interval" : "5m"
            },
            "aggs": {
              "total_value_five_mins": {
                "sum": {
                  "script": {
                     "inline": "doc.sales.value / 300"
                  }
                }
              }
            }

        }
    }
}
```